# Using WSDCreateHttpAddress

Tags: c++, windows, wsd

I'm trying to use 'Web Services on Devices' functions
as listed at that link,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386286(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm quite new with that functions so I may missed some very basic things.

I tried use the 'WSDCreateHttpAddress' function.

Code:

```
IWSDHttpAddress *addr;
HRESULT res = WSDCreateHttpAddress(&addr);
```

I got this error

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WSDCreateHttpAddress@4

I know that some library is missing but don't know where to look.

I'm using VS2015.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to link again Wsdapi.dll as explained here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386298(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't see how this link helps. I tried to clean and rebuild but still stay with same link error. @benjarobin